# Marionette Itemview click is triggered multiple times

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am seeing the click event is triggered multiple times for each row on the itemview

```
 return Marionette.ItemView.extend( {
     template: ItemViewTemplate,
     tagName: 'tr',
     className: 'ItemRow',

     templateHelpers: viewHelpers,

     events: {
        'click .editRowItem': 'editRowItem'
```

The editRowItem() function is triggered multiple times. What is the correct way to trigger the  click just on that particular row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it shouldn't trigger multiple times. It can happen however, for example when:

- Nested elements with the same class in a view. Event bubbling will cause multiple events to be fired.
- Parent views listening to click events on a class which is present in some or all children views.

An example (stripped non-relevant parts):

```
<script type="text/template" id="movie-list-item">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success some-button">
        <span class="some-button">Click here</span>
    </button>
</script>
```

---

```
// Itemview
var movieItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#movie-list-item",
    ui: {
        viewButton: '.some-button'
    },
    events: {
        'click @ui.viewButton': 'clickHandler'
    },
    clickHandler: function(ev) {
        // Log the click
        console.log('There was a click in an itemView!');

        // Uncomment the following to prevent multiple events:
        //ev.stopPropagation();
    }
});

// Composite view
var movieCompView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#movie-list",
    itemView: movieItemView,
    ui: {
        viewButton: '.some-button'
    },
    events: {
        'click @ui.viewButton': 'clickHandler'
    },
    clickHandler: function(ev) {
        // Log the click
        console.log('There was a click in a collectionView!');

        // Uncomment the following to prevent multiple events:
        //ev.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cardiff/7d3fC/2/

Note the following, if we don't use `ev.stopPropagation()` in this case to prevent the event from bubbling, the console will log 4 entries; being two for the itemView and two for the collectionView. To prevent this behaviour (and you shouldn't use a click event in the collectionView in this case) and thus receive one instead of two events we use `ev.stopPropagation()`.

Also keep in mind that using the `ui` attribute of a view to describe the components is considered good practice and can make your life a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

Just try following if you want to apply click event to each row item in the template:

```
events: {
  'click' : 'editRowItem'
}
```